# View.Measure failing on ArgumentException with SlidingMenuSharp

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, slidingmenu

I am using SlidingMenuSharp (https://github.com/Cheesebaron/SlidingMenuSharp). At random times my app crashes on the error below. I was not able to identify the reason - menu doesnt have to be manipulated or even open at the time of error. Also I have no callstack with this error, so I dont know "who" calls this and when.

```
05-22 16:30:30.340 I/MonoDroid(30088): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentException: 'jobject' must not be IntPtr.Zero. 05-22 16:30:30.340 I/MonoDroid(30088): Parameter name: jobject 
05-22 16:30:30.340 I/MonoDroid(30088): at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod (intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) [0x00010] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.12-series/7f0e3d3c/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:499 
05-22 16:30:30.340 I/MonoDroid(30088): at Android.Views.View.Measure (int,int) [0x0002d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.12-series/7f0e3d3c/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-14/src/generated/Android.Views.View.cs:10375 
05-22 16:30:30.340 I/MonoDroid(30088): at SlidingMenuSharp.CustomViewAbove.OnMeasure (int,int) [0x0002c] in d:\Devel\speedcamsprototype\Application\Android\SlidingMenuSharp\CustomViewAbove.cs:339 
05-22 16:30:30.340 I/MonoDroid(30088): at Android.Views.View.n_OnMeasure_II (intptr,intptr,int,int) [0x00009] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.12-series/7f0e3d3c/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-14/src/generated/Android.Views.View.cs:11378 
05-22 16:30:30.340 I/MonoDroid(30088): at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.bd42ef49-55d3-4861-a730-0897a6e73e12 (intptr,intptr,int,int) <IL 0x0001d, 0x0004b>
```

Any ideas what is going on? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, by long trial and error process i found the reason. If you work with layouts in the activity which is using SlidingMenuSharp this way :

```
using (var mainlayout = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.mainLayout))
{
    mainLayout.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.bg_blue);
}
```

you will get the exception in the question. However, if you dont use `using` (and i guess leave more time for some attached stuff to react, before GC dispose the reference?), everything works fine.

```
var mainlayout = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.mainLayout);
mainLayout.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.bg_blue);
```

Maybe it is more like workaround - I guess they should still fix this in SlidingMenuSharp somehow, but it works for now.